# State is updated, also its reflecting with props, in console.log, however the component is not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The **state is updated**, also **its giving the latest data to props with mapStateToProps**, however, **its not rendering the child component StudentList and Student in *Map method***, once the props is updated.

Once you **add student**, you can see the updated state, which is sent to the Form component.

Here is my code,

**Index.js**

```
   var store = createStore(studentFormReducer);

    ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));

    // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
    // unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.

    serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import StudentFormContainer from './containers/StudentFormContainer';
import StudentList from './components/StudentList'


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <StudentFormContainer></StudentFormContainer>
                <StudentList></StudentList>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**StudentForm : Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

 export default class StudentForm extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            student : {
                name:"",

            }
        };

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="formcontainer">
                <button type="button" name="addstudent" id="addstudent" onClick={(e)=>{this.props.addStudent(this.state.student); console.log(this.props.currentstate)}} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg ">Add student</button>
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="name">Student name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value={this.state.student.name} onChange={(e)=>{e.preventDefault(); this.setState({student:{name : e.target.value}})}} className="form-control" placeholder="Enter student name" aria-describedby="helpId"/>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**StudentFormContainer : Container**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import StudentForm from '../components/StudentForm'
import {addStudentAction} from '../actions/index'

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    console.log("New state updated");
    return{
        studentlist : state.studentlist,
        currentstate : state
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
    return{
        addStudent : (student)=>{console.log("Dispatching");dispatch(addStudentAction(student))}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(StudentForm)
```

**StudentList : Component + Container**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import Student from './Student'

class StudentList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="studentlist">

                {this.props.studentlist.map(
                    (student,index)=>(<Student key={index} student={student}></Student>))
                }
                </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{

    return{
        studentlist : state.studentlist,
        currentstate : state
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(StudentList)
```

**Student Form Reducer**

```
export const studentFormReducer = (state={},action)=>{
    if(action.type=="ADD_STUDENT"){
        var id = state.studentlist.length+1;
        action.student.id = id;
        state.studentlist.push(action.student);
        return state;
    }
    else{
        if(state.studentlist===undefined){
            var newstate2 = {studentlist:[]}
            return newstate2;
        }else{
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

**Action**

```
export const addStudentAction = (student)=>
{
    return{
        type : "ADD_STUDENT",
        student : student
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state` should be immutable. In your code you manipulated directly the `state` object.

```
state.studentlist.push(action.student);
```

Using [object spread operator](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator), you will be able to fix this:

```
switch(action.type) {
  case "ADD_STUDENT":
    let student = action.student;
    student.id = state.studentList.length + 1; // set student id
    return {
      ...state,
      studentList: [
        ...state.studentList,
        student // add new student to student list
      ]
    };
  default:
    return state;
}
```

Comment: i think studentlist property will be like this.
 studentList: [...state.studentList, student]

Comment: @BinodShrestha, you're right. thought I had a variable for `studentList`. thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Codekaizer, this worked perfectly fine. Also I have query in mutating state, so we should be using the same syntax ...state only, or can we also copy state to a new variable, like var newstate = state and make changes and return the newstate object ?

Comment: @MrunmayDeswandikar, yes. you can create a copy of `state` and return the `newstate` object. `let newstate = {...state}; // don't forget ...`

Comment: Thanks for the update. As I used simply var newstate = state. And then updated the newstate object, but still it was not working. Will try with {..state} this one.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are trying to add new student and update that student object into existing array if i am not wrong. it's not the good choise to use if-condition in reducer function better use switch case.

```js
const initialState = {
  studentlist: []
}

export const studentFormReducer = (state=initialState, action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case "ADD_STUDENT":
      return{
        ...state,
        studentlist: [...state.studentlist, action.student]
      }
     default: 
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes you are right, we should not use if else in reducers. We should be using Switch.  But this is just a demo code, just to get hands on for react-redux :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in reducer

```
case ADD_STUDENT :
    return { 
        ...state,
        studentList: state.studentList.concat(action.student)
    }
```

Comment: You're making a lot of assumptions about the users program and understanding of JS with this answer. Though its best practice, they haven't declared the `ADD_STUDENT` action type constant anywhere so you should leave this a string or explain where this variable originates. Also, I'd suggest writing out full `switch statement` since they're currently using a conditional.

Comment: @cantuket, Actions are defined with a special actions js file. Its now added in the question.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly ! Can you please explain how it worked fine. Should we keep state unchanged, and just copy it to other object ?

Comment: this doesn't set the `student.id`.

Comment: Yes @Codekaizer, though he havent added that line, but I have added it to his solution while implementing !